# Hashing or converting static file names like images in angular 4

Tags: angular, security, hash

I have a requirement where I would want to hide the file name of my assets like images.Like using output hashing we can hash chunks similarly I would want to hash my images file name. I am using angular 4.

Comment: output hashing is used to avoid browser caching, not for obfuscating file names. Do you want the later?

Comment: Yes, as its a security compliance to not reveal the file name